# Is using Transactional APIs mandatory in simple FAQ bot related to fleet management for Google Asssistant?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to deploy my FAQ bot in beta production of google assistant . But Google team kept rejecting my bot by saying 
"Your app allows transactional bookings or reservations. Please note that any app completing transactions (paid or non-paid) must use the Transactions API.
For more information about transactions policy, please visit this page: https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/general-policies#transactions".

In my FAQ bot i am not making any transaction through any Intents. All intents are non paid intents but still google keep saying that i have to use transactional api . Any one from actions on google team help me to solve this problem  then it would be great .

Thank you

Comment: We had a problem with our app being flagged as transactional, which we solved by [raising a support request](https://developers.google.com/actions/support/) and explaining what we were doing. The support team were very helpful, though it took a bit of back-and-forth to get back into the directory.

Comment: Noted. Thank you !